# I'm trying to connect the database Postgresql to the Dockerfile, but I can't connect to it,

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, connection

> **My docker-compose.yml file**

```
 version: '3'

 services:
 postgres:
image: 'postgres:14.2'
container_name: 'java-postgres'
environment:
  - 'POSTGRES_USER= postgres'
  - 'POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD= trust'
  - 'POSTGRES_DB= postgres'

app:
build: ./
container_name: 'e-book-app'
ports:
  - 8080:8080
```

> **My application.properties file**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1GB
spring.datasource.password = nurba1713
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

> **My Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD /e-book/target/e-book-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar e-book.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","e-book.jar"]
```

> **But i get this error, i don't know how to fix it, sorry for such a stupid question, I'm newable**

```
         org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at
   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:319) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar!/:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar!/:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar!/:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar!/:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar!/:42.3.3]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core
-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:18
1) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.
5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.
5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/
:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.F
inal]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6
.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Fina
l]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Fin
al.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.
6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6
.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Fina
l]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final] 
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]  
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.
6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) [hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5
.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:
58) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [sp
ring-orm-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) [spring-orm-5.3.
16.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) [spring-orm-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.
16]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.3.1
6.jar!/:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) [spring-bea
ns-5.3.16.jar!/:5.3.16]
```

> I also tried to change spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres to spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres, in this case the jar file is not going.

Comment: `localhost` in Docker usually means "the current container", not a different container or something running outside a container on the same host.  Use the database's Compose service name `postgres` as the hostname in the `spring.datasource.url` property (or, better, specify `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` in the Compose file).

Comment: @DavidMaze 
 spring.datasource.url -> I tried to do this, but the jar file is not being built
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:14.2'
    container_name: 'java-postgres'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER= postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD= trust'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB= postgres'
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:db://db:5432/postgres'
if I understood you correctly, I should have done so, but it doesn't work